# Process and update each row in SQL efficiently

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-masking

TL;DR:
What is an efficient way to loop through 500k rows, apply a custom transformation logic/ciper to a column (or few, perhaps) in each single row, and update the column with the transformed data? 
Is there a way to do it efficiently in SQL without having to write a separate program to loop through each row and apply the logic?

Background:
We have a table (~500k rows), and some columns contains sensitive data that needs to be masked. As we are masking identity columns that are used in joins, the masking needs to be consistent across all other tables. After much consideration with MD5 / CRC / hashing algorithms we decided to just stick with our own cipher algorithm that will guarantee uniqueness without ending up with too many meaningless characters.

Comment: Why would you need to mask "identity" columns? A primary key does not contain any any sensitive data - it's just a unique number

Comment: Instead of changing the data, why not create views that return the "masked" data? Something like this: https://blog.taadeem.net/english/2018/10/29/Introducing-PostgreSQL-Anonymizer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the values in place, then you need to be sure that the types are compatible -- the existing column has the same type as the destination column.  Then:

```
update t
    set col = my_cipher(col);
```

This is relatively expensive because every row is being updated.

If the types are not the same, then you have a bigger challenge.  It sounds like the columns you want to change are foreign keys.  You probably need to drop all foreign key constraints and modify the tables so the columns have the same type, change the values, and then add the foreign keys back in.